# In XAML, Why a Transparent background blocks this Trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml

This happens only when I set the background to Transparent, which is the effect that I need. Changing the background to AliceBlue for example, allows the trigger to take an effect. 
What could be missing here behind the scenes?

```
<Window
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent">
<Window.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Window.IsActive" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Window.Cursor" Value="ArrowCD" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock>
        Some Text    
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a side effect of how [layered windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx#layerwin_topic2b) are handled at the Win32 level: wholly transparent pixels (i.e., with zero alpha) are not visible to hit testing, and therefore will not generate mouse events.

Since all mouse events pass through your window, your window's cursor will not be displayed.  So, while your trigger may fire, it is rendered useless by the hit testing behavior.  Even if you hard-code the window's `Cursor` property to `ArrowCD`, you will never see that cursor unless the mouse is over non-transparent content within the window.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to play around with Window Opacity. It appears to work, but even though I am setting the opacity to .1, the window appears darker, not clear as expected.

Comment: You _could_ use a low-alpha color like `#01FFFFFF` or `#01000000` as the background, but the effect may be visible to a discerning eye.

Comment: He could attach the hit test to an object instead of the window, a `Rectangle` for example with a `Transparent` `Fill` will accept hit test. I float them over content to accomplish this type of thing often.

Comment: Thanks. I feel very satisfied with the low-alpha color #01000000. Just to point out, it needs AllowsTransparency="True". I found more on this [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ae8a8a21-9c68-4987-8480-a2f03a161784/mouse-over-transparent-control-doesnt-generate-events)

Comment: @ChrisW. Do you have any links that could demonstrate what you mean? Sounds interesting...

Comment: Nah, no links, just a trick I use to fire off triggers sometimes when I also need transparency. So say for example; <Grid><Object/><Object/><Rectangle Fill="Transparent><Triggers/></Rectangle></Grid> will put your hittest area over your content and fire your triggers since your other stuff sits behind it.

Comment: If the transparent `Rectangle` is within a transparent `Window`, it still won't receive any input events.  The top-level HWND has to receive events from the Win32 layer before WPF can process them, and that's not going to happen for the reasons I explained.